# Session return to false via Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I was able to check `Auth::check()` via controller before redirecting to my other route that needed to passthrough a middleware to check if the `Auth::check() == true`, however, when i'm trying to check the value of `Auth::check()` via my Middleware it returned a `FALSE / NULL` value. Any Idea guys ??

Did the following already:

- Set session via ENV file to `database`
- Tried using multiple Guard as i needed this feature. though for the sake of making it working first, i disabled the Guard setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When Laravel is running through your middlewares, the authentication code still hasn't ran and hence why you get `null` as if there was no user logged in.

Enclose the routes in your `web.php` which utilize `Authenticate` middleware with the `auth` middleware.

That's when your `Auth` facade will work the same way it'd work in your controller.